# Java Object in list doesn't get found

Tags: java, list, stream

I have a problem. I have the following class:

```
public class Cross implements Comparable<Cross> {
    
    private Long openTime;
    private String market;
    private String coin;
    private String period;
    private String metric1;
    private String metric2;
    private Double close;
    private String trend;


    public Long getOpenTime() {
        return this.openTime;
    }

    public void setOpenTime(long openTime) {
        this.openTime = openTime;
    }

    public String getMarket() {
        return this.market;
    }

    public void setMarket(String market) {
        this.market = market;
    }

    public String getCoin() {
        return this.coin;
    }

    public void setCoin(String coin) {
        this.coin = coin;
    }

    public String getPeriod() {
        return this.period;
    }

    public void setPeriod(String period) {
        this.period = period;
    }

    public String getMetric1() {
        return this.metric1;
    }

    public void setMetric1(String metric1) {
        this.metric1 = metric1;
    }

    public String getMetric2() {
        return this.metric2;
    }

    public void setMetric2(String metric2) {
        this.metric2 = metric2;
    }

    public Double getClose() {
        return this.close;
    }

    public void setClose(double close) {
        this.close = close;
    }

    public String getTrend() {
        return this.trend;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {

        if (object != null && object instanceof Cross) {
            Cross cross = (Cross) object;
            return (
                openTime.equals(cross.getOpenTime()) &&
                market.equals(cross.getMarket()) &&
                coin.equals(cross.getCoin()) &&
                period.equals(cross.getPeriod()) &&
                metric1.equals(cross.getMetric1()) &&
                metric2.equals(cross.getMetric2())
            );
        }

        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cross o) {
        return this.getOpenTime().compareTo(o.getOpenTime());
    }

}
```

Now I have a list containing 500 objects of these elements. Here are the first 4 shown:

```
{ openTime='1504332000000', market='USDT', coin='ETH', period='2h', metric1='EMA12', metric2='EMA26', close='363.7', trend='Down'}
{ openTime='1504663200000', market='USDT', coin='ETH', period='2h', metric1='EMA12', metric2='EMA26', close='325.73', trend='Up'}
{ openTime='1504879200000', market='USDT', coin='ETH', period='2h', metric1='EMA12', metric2='EMA26', close='294.05', trend='Down'}
{ openTime='1505181600000', market='USDT', coin='ETH', period='2h', metric1='EMA12', metric2='EMA26', close='304.41', trend='Up'}
```

In a variable I have stored the epoch of a specific datetime and with that I want to find the first valid cross, so I tried this:

```
private Cross getValidCross(List<Cross> crossList, LocalDateTime runDateTimeGMT0) {
    long searchEpoch = runDateTimeGMT0.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) * 1000;
    return crossList.stream().filter(cross -> cross.getOpenTime() < searchEpoch).max(Cross::compareTo).orElse(null);
}
```

But this code returns the value `null` When my `searchEpoch` is for example: `1514764800000`. In the list I do see multiple objects that have a lower `openTime` than the `searchEpoch`. The result I want is the cross with the highest `openTime`, but it still has to be smaller than the `searchEpoch`.

Here is the error I get:

```
runDateTimeGMT0: 2018-01-01T00:00
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at com.hatop.drivers.SimulatorDriver.run(SimulatorDriver.java:297)
        at com.hatop.drivers.HatopDriver.main(HatopDriver.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.hatop.models.Cross.getTrend()" because the return value of "com.hatop.drivers.HatopDriver.getValidCross(List<Cross>, LocalDateTime)" 
is null
        at com.hatop.strategies.modules.module_java001.run(module_java001.java:186)
        ... 6 more
```

Why is my return value `null`?

Comment: does crossList contains crosses with openTime before 1 january 2018?

Comment: Yess, the first 4 crosses I printed in my question are from before 2018. Is it because I can't use the `<`, `=` and `>` operators on the type `Long`?

Comment: your code works for me: https://www.online-ide.com/BiGKP7epSr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused due to the value the argument `runDateTimeGMT0` is given and this:

```
long searchEpoch = runDateTimeGMT0.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) * 1000;
```

Since this is working:

```
public class Demo {
    private static Cross getValidCross(List<Cross> crossList, LocalDateTime runDateTimeGMT0) {
        long searchEpoch = 1514764800000L;

        return crossList.stream()
                .filter(cross -> cross.getOpenTime() < searchEpoch)
                .max(Cross::compareTo)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Cross> crosses = Arrays.asList(
                new Cross(1504332000000L, "USDT", "ETH", "2h", "EMA12", "EMA26", 363.7, "Down"),
                new Cross(1504663200000L, "USDT", "ETH", "2h", "EMA12", "EMA26", 325.73, "Up"),
                new Cross(1504879200000L, "USDT", "ETH", "2h", "EMA12", "EMA26", 294.05, "Down"),
                new Cross(1505181600000L, "USDT", "ETH", "2h", "EMA12", "EMA26", 304.41, "Up")
        );

        Cross validCross = getValidCross(crosses, null);

        System.out.println(validCross);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Cross(openTime=1505181600000, market=USDT, coin=ETH, period=2h, metric1=EMA12, metric2=EMA26, close=304.41, trend=Up)
```

By the way, `equals()` is implemented without `hashcode()` - a recipe for problems.

Comment: I still don't understand how I can fix my problem. What can I do different with this line: `long searchEpoch = runDateTimeGMT0.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) * 1000;`???

Comment: That depends on what `openTime` is. Is it seconds from epoch?

Comment: `openTime` is the epoch in milliseconds, thats why I do the `seachEpoch` * `1000`

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk actually this works for me as well: `Cross validCross = getValidCross(crosses, LocalDateTime.now();`

Comment: Isn't it weird that you get a result on that one??? The openTime is lower than the searchEpoch?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk sorry I made a mistake, I fixed now

Comment: Output for `LocalDateTime.now()`: `Cross(openTime=1505181600000, market=USDT, coin=ETH, period=2h, metric1=EMA12, metric2=EMA26, close=304.41, trend=Up)`

Comment: Weird.... I have added the error to my question, but I have no idea what to do now ?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Could it be that you call `.getTrend()` on the result that is 'null'?

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that the result should not be null, because there is a cross

Answer (score 0):

I tested you code by passing the value in a proper `Cross` constructor, as it appears in your list and it works fine. In particular, `openingTime` is passed as primitive type `long`.

The issue is NOT in the filter, as you can definitely use any operator with `Long` type.

In my opinion, there is something wrong in the file format of your `Cross` object. Highly likely is because of the `openingTime` field's value, which is probably converted in the wrong value.

Here is the test I wrote:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.List;

public class TestCross {
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Cross> crossList = List.of(new Cross(1504332000000L,"USDT", "ETH", "2h","EMA12", "EMA26",363.7,"Down" ), 
                                        new Cross(1505181600000L,"USDT", "ETH", "2h","EMA12", "EMA26",304.41,"Up" ),
                                        new Cross(1504663200000L,"USDT", "ETH", "2h","EMA12", "EMA26",325.73,"Up" ),
                                        new Cross(1504879200000L,"USDT", "ETH", "2h","EMA12", "EMA26",294.05,"Down" ));
                                        
                                        
        Cross cross = new TestCross().getValidCross(crossList, LocalDateTime.now());
        System.out.println(cross);

    }
    
    private Cross getValidCross(List<Cross> crossList, LocalDateTime runDateTimeGMT0) {
        long searchEpoch = runDateTimeGMT0.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) * 1000;
        return crossList.stream().filter(cross -> cross.getOpenTime() < searchEpoch).max(Cross::compareTo).orElse(null);
    }

}
```

`Cross` class

```
public class Cross implements Comparable<Cross> {
    
    public Cross(Long openTime, String market, String coin, String period, String metric1, String metric2, Double close,
            String trend) {
        super();
        this.openTime = openTime;
        this.market = market;
        this.coin = coin;
        this.period = period;
        this.metric1 = metric1;
        this.metric2 = metric2;
        this.close = close;
        this.trend = trend;
    }


    private Long openTime;
    private String market;
    private String coin;
    private String period;
    private String metric1;
    private String metric2;
    private Double close;
    private String trend;
    
    


    public Long getOpenTime() {
        return this.openTime;
    }

    public void setOpenTime(long openTime) {
        this.openTime = openTime;
    }

    public String getMarket() {
        return this.market;
    }

    public void setMarket(String market) {
        this.market = market;
    }

    public String getCoin() {
        return this.coin;
    }

    public void setCoin(String coin) {
        this.coin = coin;
    }

    public String getPeriod() {
        return this.period;
    }

    public void setPeriod(String period) {
        this.period = period;
    }

    public String getMetric1() {
        return this.metric1;
    }

    public void setMetric1(String metric1) {
        this.metric1 = metric1;
    }

    public String getMetric2() {
        return this.metric2;
    }

    public void setMetric2(String metric2) {
        this.metric2 = metric2;
    }

    public Double getClose() {
        return this.close;
    }

    public void setClose(double close) {
        this.close = close;
    }

    public String getTrend() {
        return this.trend;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {

        if (object != null && object instanceof Cross) {
            Cross cross = (Cross) object;
            return (
                openTime.equals(cross.getOpenTime()) &&
                market.equals(cross.getMarket()) &&
                coin.equals(cross.getCoin()) &&
                period.equals(cross.getPeriod()) &&
                metric1.equals(cross.getMetric1()) &&
                metric2.equals(cross.getMetric2())
            );
        }

        return false;
    }
    
    


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cross [openTime=" + openTime + ", market=" + market + ", coin=" + coin + ", period=" + period
                + ", metric1=" + metric1 + ", metric2=" + metric2 + ", close=" + close + ", trend=" + trend + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cross o) {
        return this.getOpenTime().compareTo(o.getOpenTime());
    }

}
```

And here is the output:

```
Cross [openTime=1505181600000, market=USDT, coin=ETH, period=2h, metric1=EMA12, metric2=EMA26, close=304.41, trend=Up]
```